# Why are my radiators not heating up?

Tags: heating, radiator

The boiler is on; the pipe near the boiler is hot, but the pipes furthest away are cold. What does that mean, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

There could be air trapped in your system - that is if the pump is working. You might have to bleed the system at the burner and/or at the radiotors.

[image]

And a good flush could help, but you might need help with that.

[image]

- A : Bleeding valve
- B : Trapped Air
- E : Reducer boiler performance

Answer (score 4):

There are different water heating systems, but I'd check if the the pump that is pushing hot water through the pipes is working.

A circulating pump in a central heating system typically [looks like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=central+heating+pump&hl=en&tbm=isch).

[image]

You can tell if your pump is working by:

- Checking if the pipe is cold or hot each side of the pump. If it gets
  cold a foot or two after the pump, it is not working.
- Checking if it hums or vibrates when the heating is on.
- You should hear the water flow through the pipes when it's on.

Comment: Sorry for the short answer, I edited it.